# Making an ext3 filesystem image without mkfs.ext3

Tags: linux, shell-script, ext3

On ubuntu I'm using the following to create a ext3 filesystem image `system.img`.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=./system.img bs=1000000 count=200
mkfs.ext3 ./system.img
```

I'm attempting to do the same on android platform. But the problem is I can't find a `mkfs.ext3` binary for armv7 android. But I have `mkfs.ext2` , `mke2fs` , `tune2fs` and `e2fsck`. So my question is, Is it possible to achieve the same result with the available binaries? If yes, how to do it?

Comment: Is your problem that you can't find a binary for Android (in which case, just make one, a statically compiled BusyBox), or that you need to rely on existing binaries (in which case, beware that different OEMs and different releases of Android come with different sets of utilities)?

Comment: @Gilles I'm making this app for only one phone, I tried to compile `e2fsprogs` for armv7 It cant be compiled statically, it uses dynamic. I'm fairly new to cross compiling so I didn't succeed. But It'll be nice if someone have already done it.

Comment: My bad, I checked, and BusyBox does not in fact support ext3 or ext4 (it accepts but ignores a filesystem type argument). So you'd need to make a statically compiled e2fsprogs or install a Linux in a chroot; both are possible, but overkill given that you have a solution with the tools you already have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually yes. Since ext2 and ext3 are fairly similar, with the major difference being ext3 supports journalling, you should be able to:

```
tune2fs -j ./system.img
```

Which enables journalling. The conversion process [is detailed here](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/ext2toext3.htm) with the usual disclaimers about important information, messing with filesystems etc.

You can actually go back to ext2 too, if needed, by removing the journal. Also note - you'll need to change any auto-mount options to `ext3` to actually enable use of the journal.

Comment: good one. Is not the journaling support natively available on android? I am surprised. So what is the default fs on it?

Comment: @NikhilMulley I'm... not sure. I checked my `mount` output and `vfat` shows up - I'm guessing its the default much as it is for MP3 players and other small devices. Various parts (system images by the look of it) are mounted `ro`, too, which makes journalling unnecessary even if fat supported it.

Comment: so I would use `mkfs.ext2 ./system.img && tune2fs -j ./system.img` right?

Comment: yep I can conirm that it works,  `$ file system.img 
system.img: Linux rev 1.0 ext3 filesystem data, UUID=168a5dd8-26b0-423b-abdf-545c5a8a8ab0`. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

mkfs.ext[234] are all symlinks to `mke2fs`, so just run `mke2fs -F -T ext3 ./system.img`.

Comment: `/mnt/sdcard # mke2fs -t ext3 system.img 
unknown option -- tBusyBox v1.19.4-cm9 bionic (2012-02-05 18:40 +0100) multi-call binary.

Usage: mke2fs [-Fn] [-b BLK_SIZE] [-i INODE_RATIO] [-I INODE_SIZE] [-m RESERVED_PERCENT] [-L LABEL] BLOCKDEV [KBYTES]

 -b BLK_SIZE Block size, bytes
 -F  Force
 -i RATIO Max number of files is filesystem_size / RATIO
 -I BYTES Inode size (min 128)
 -L LBL  Volume label
 -m PERCENT Percent of blocks to reserve for admin
 -n  Dry run
` I get this when I run that.

Comment: That's a typo in your answer. The right one is `mke2fs -F -T ext3 system.img`

Comment: @BinoyBabu Strange; his way should work with a standard `mke2fs` (other than forgetting the device); it must be something with Busybox

Comment: It didn't work, It created the fs sucessfully but the created fs turned out to be ext2. Some werid problem with busybox. `$ file system.img 
system.img: Linux rev 1.0 ext2 filesystem data, UUID=cf32ba30-2a3f-402d-9c05-43fbcd298d11`

Comment: @BinoyBabu, why don't you just create the image on your computer with real mke2fs and then transfer it to the phone?

Comment: @BinoyBabu, actually it is technically supposed to be a lower case t as I originally wrote, though in practice, either one works.

Comment: @psusi Interestingly lower case `t` don't work with busybox. The man page in ubuntu specifies upper case `T` by the way. I can't transfer the file from pc because I'm developing an app that could make these images. For now I think I'll stick with `tune2fs` method. Thanks anyway. Your answer was real informative.

Comment: From ubuntu `$ mke2fs  --help` outputs `Usage: mke2fs [-c|-l filename] [-b block-size] [-C cluster-size]
 [-i bytes-per-inode] [-I inode-size] [-J journal-options]
 [-G meta group size] [-N number-of-inodes]
 [-m reserved-blocks-percentage] [-o creator-os]
 [-g blocks-per-group] [-L volume-label] [-M last-mounted-directory]
 [-O feature[,...]] [-r fs-revision] [-E extended-option[,...]]
 [-T fs-type] [-U UUID] [-jnqvFKSV] device [blocks-count]
`

Comment: By the way do you know how to specify journal options for ext3 (using -J switch)?

Comment: @BinoyBabu, the man page specifies -t for the fs type ( ext2, ext3, ext4 ), and -T for the usage type ( like largefile ).  It looks like --help is incorrect.

Comment: You might be right. I've got it working anyway. Happy coding.

Comment: @psusi BionyBabu has the [BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/) version of `mke2fs`, not the more complete one from e2fsprogs normally found on non-embedded systems. The BusyBox version only supports ext2, and most of the options it accepts are in fact silently ignored.